# Java Uri Writing Permission Denial

Tags: android, uri

How to Handle Following Exception

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: writing com.android.providers.media.......requires android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS, or grantUriPermission()
```

I Already Have Added following permissions in androidManifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /><uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS"/>
```

The code is as follows

I have An Array of Uri

```
AddArry[]

try{   
        getContentResolver().releasePersistableUriPermission(AddArray[i],Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
        grantUriPermission(getApplicationContext().getPackageCodePath(),AddArray[i],Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);

        parcelFileDescriptor = getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor((Uri)AddArray[i],"w");
        fileDescriptor = parcelFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor();

}
catch(Exception e){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
ExifInterface ei = new ExifInterface(fileDescriptor);

ei.setAttribute(TAG_GPS_LATITUDE, "33/1,35/1,4091/100");
ei.setAttribute(TAG_GPS_LATITUDE_REF, "N");
ei.setAttribute(TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE, "73/1,1/1,4390/100");
ei.setAttribute(TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE_REF, "E");


try {
    ei.saveAttributes();
} catch (Exception e) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to use an uri of which you just released the permission?

Comment: actuyllay i am trying to update LatLng of some images.

Comment: Of course. Thats what we thought already. What else could it have been.

Comment: Source of Exception is 
parcelFileDescriptor = getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor((Uri)AddArray[i],"w");
it works fine if i Just ("r") Read. But Generate exception on "rw" and "w"

Comment: `Why are you trying to use an uri of which you just released the permission?`

Comment: I have just updated the code

Comment: is there anyother way to handle this issue??

Comment: I already asked twice and do it again: `Why are you trying to use an uri of which you just released the permission? `.

Comment: I hope i have understood ur question this time ...
I select multiple images from image gallery. Data is converted to Uri and saved in array. Now i want to update LatLng of these selected Images via Uri.

Comment: No. That is not an answer. I was asking about releasing a permission. Why are you doing that?

Comment: Exception says "requires android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS, or grantUriPermission() "

Comment: Yes. So why are you releasing a permission which you need? You had got the permission and you throw it away. Why throwing away a needed permission?

Comment: i think i should comment release permission line. .....

Comment: Yes. And the next line. You cannot grand yourself such a permission.

Comment: ok. then how to edit Exif Data of file via uri??

Comment: You did not tell the result/effect of removing those two lines.

Comment: it throws  same Exception Permission Denail.....

Comment: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: writing com.android.providers.media.......requires android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS, or grantUriPermission()

Comment: Please post complete reproducable code. Starting with the intent. Post onActivityResult code. Choose one picture and handle one picture. If we can just copy and paste your code to try it out there might be people who do so. Update your post. Start with telling that "r" goes ok and "w" fails. I do not understand that you omitted this valuable info.

Comment: Further it has nothing to do with exif interface as your problem starts before with obtaining a file descripter.